# jQuery tabs: how to hide single tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

How do I hide the tab2? I can add ID to the second ***li*** and than hide it with jQuery, but isn't there some way to do it through .tabs directly?

```
<div id="tabs" style="width:100%">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#tab1">
            Tab 1 Title
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#tab2">
            Tab 2 Title
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="tab1" style="width:100%;">
    content tab1
 ....
```

Comment: provide fiddle will be more helpfull

Comment: question is little confusing, do you want to hide anchor with href="#tab2" or there is one more div with id="tab2" (as I can see div with id="tab1"?

Comment: I have two tabs, containing two different graphs. First one will always have graph with data, the second one may not have any data for the graph, in that case it should hide the tab. Your answer has worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('[href="#tab2"]').closest('li').hide();
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
  $($("#tabs").find("li")[1]).hide()
```

Answer (score 3):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/DdsLY/)**

HTML:

```
<div id='MyTabSelector'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 0</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
      <a href="#" onclick="$('#MyTabSelector').disableTab(1);">Disable Tab 1</a><br />
```

JS:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.disableTab = function (tabIndex, hide) {
    // Get the array of disabled tabs, if any
    var disabledTabs = this.tabs("option", "disabled");

    if ($.isArray(disabledTabs)) {
        var pos = $.inArray(tabIndex, disabledTabs);

        if (pos < 0) {
            disabledTabs.push(tabIndex);
        }
    }
    else {
        disabledTabs = [tabIndex];
    }

    this.tabs("option", "disabled", disabledTabs);

    if (hide === true) {
        $(this).find('li:eq(' + tabIndex + ')').addClass('ui-state-hidden');
    }

    // Enable chaining
    return this;
};

$.fn.enableTab = function (tabIndex) {
            $(this).find('li:eq(' + tabIndex + ')').removeClass('ui-state-hidden');
    this.tabs("enable", tabIndex);
    return this;

};


})(jQuery);
$('#MyTabSelector').tabs();
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to hide both li as well as div to hide tab
so your jquery would be

```
$($("#tabs").find("li")[1]).hide();
$($("#tabs").find('#tab2')).hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
//when you click a tab
$('#tabs a').click(function(){
    //show hidden tabs again
    $('#tabs li:hidden').show();
    //hide the clicked tab
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```